# Resetting MySQL root password Mac Error 1131

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

I'm trying to reset my password for root in mysql installed on Mac OS Sierra. I keep getting this error: `ERROR 1131 (42000): You are using MySQL as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to change passwords`.

Here's what I type in as commands:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If there's nothing in your MySQL database, shut the `mysqld` process down, nuke out its data directory, and reconstruct it with `mysql_install_db`, perhaps?